# How many clusters would you divide this dendrogram into?

Tags: clustering, dendrogram

[image]

I'm struggling as to where to cut this dendrogram: any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't change any number of classes until I had independent evidence that the classes are distinct enough and make sense enough for my purposes. That's a serious answer, flippant though it may sound. The dendrogram is just one summary of evidence and shows many possible solutions. It's rare that just one solution leaps out from a dendrogram as obviously best.

Comment: Looks almost **fractal** to me, in particular if you would move the top branch to the bottom. That may indicate that your similarity measure isn't good yet, maybe?

Comment: Because an edit deleted the link to the image, I have rolled this post back to its original version.

Comment: Looking on the relative length of the links, I see 2, 4 or 7 clusters.

Comment: In my comment please read "choose" for "change". I'd plot places (for I think those are the observations) in something like the space of the first 2 PCs.